# i get runtime error when doing kattis oddmanout challenge

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Hi im new to Kattis ive done this assignment "oddmanout" and it works when i compile it locally but i get runtime error doing it via Kattis. Im not sure why?

```
from collections import Counter

cases = int(input())
i = 0
case = 0

while cases > i:
    list = []
    i = 1 + i
    case = case + 1

    guests = int(input())   

    f = 0

    while f < guests:
        f = f + 1

        invitation_number = int(input()) 

        list.append(invitation_number)

        d =  Counter(list)
        res = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]

        resnew = str(res)[1:-1] 

    print(f'Case#{case}: {resnew}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the input data on [Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/oddmanout) : `invitation_number = int(input())` reads not just the first integer, but the whole line of invitation numbers at once in the third line of the input. A `ValueError` is the result.

With `invitation_numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))` or alternatively `invitation_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` you will get your desired format directly.

You may have to rework your approach afterwards, since you have to get rid of the 2nd while loop. Additionally you don't have to use a counter, running through a sorted list and pairwise comparing the entries, may give you the solution aswell.

Additionally try to avoid naming your variables like the datatypes (list = list()).